# ¿ Cómo imprimir la secuencia de números mí function fibonacci?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

Tengo el siguiente dilema:
Cada nuevo término en la secuencia de Fibonacci se genera al agregar los dos términos anteriores. Al comenzar con 1 y 2, los primeros 10 términos serán:
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
Bien, he conseguido una función que me devuelve el fibonacci de un número, por ejemplo, si pido el 20, me devuelve 4181. En este caso busco imprimir la secuencia que salga de pasar el 34 a mi función.

Quiero imprimir la secuencia hasta los cuatro millones , que resulta del fibonacci del 34, para luego sacar los pares de esa secuencia, cosa que ya haré.
Pero lo que no consigo es sacar la secuencia, todos los números de la secuencia, cuyos valores no excedan de los  cuatro millones, para luego sacar los pares de estos.
He buscado en stackoverflow por: fibonacci y no me sale nada
Si pueden ayudarme.
Gracias.

```js
let contador = 1
function fibonacci(num) {
    contador++
    if (num == 1) return 0
    if (num == 2) return 1

    return  fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2)
}

fibonacci (34)
//3524578 este seria el limite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes imprimir los resultados individuales antes de regresar el valor asi:

```js
    let x = 1; 
    let y = 1; 
    let z; 
    let fin = 34 
    console.log("La Serie es:") 
    console.log(x) 
    console.log(y) 
    z = y + x 
    console.log(z); 
    for (let i = 3; i < fin - 1; i++) { 
      x = y 
      y = z 
      z = y + x 
      console.log(z) 
    }
```

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm pero repite los números pequeños al principio. He conseguido sacarlo de la siguiente forma, si lo corriges la doy buena `        let x = 1;
        let y = 1;
        let z;
        let fin = 34
        console.log("La   Serie es:")
        console.log(x)
        console.log(y)
        z = y + x
        console.log(z);
        for (let i = 3; i < fin - 1; i++) {
            x = y
            y = z
            z = y + x
            console.log(z)
        }`

Comment: ya la edite, sin usar recursion es mas facil imprimir lo que quieres

Comment: Gracias por la molestia, ahora solo me queda meter los pares de la secuencia en un array para sumarles. Espero conseguirlo.

Comment: Ya consegui sacar la suma de los pares de la secuencia-