# Project Euler. "Mismo" código, diferente resultado

Tags: javascript

Es el segundo ejercicio del "Project Euler". En C++ me da, pero en JS no.

"Cada nuevo término de la secuencia de Fibonacci se genera sumando los dos términos anteriores. Al comenzar con 1 y 2, los primeros 10 términos serán:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

Al considerar los términos en la secuencia de Fibonacci cuyos valores no exceden los cuatro millones, encuentre la suma de los términos pares."

El resultado debería ser **4613732**. Me da eso cuando lo hago en C++, al momento de hacerlo en JS me da **0**.

**Código en C++:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 1, y = 1, z;
    int result = 0;

    while (z <= 4000000) {
        z = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = z;

        if (z % 2 == 0)
            result += z;
    }

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Código en JavaScript:**

```js
let x = 1, y = 1, z;
let result = 0;

while (z <= 4000000) {
    z = x + y;
    x = y;
    y = z;

    if (z % 2 == 0)
        result += z;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: y si definis z como hiciste con el resto?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en c++, tu variable `z`, automáticamente se le da el valor de 0, y en JavaScript el valor de `z` es `undefined`, por lo tanto, nunca se entra al bucle `while`

Comment: Es importante inicializar una variable antes de usarla, en cualquier lenguaje. De hecho en C++ también podría llegar a fallar tu código si utilizar un compilador diferente. En C++ el compilador detecta ese problema e inicializa la variable en cero, sin embargo esto varía de compilador en compilador, por ejemplo, en otro podría dejar los bits de memoria exactamente como los solicitó y e iniciar con z != 0

Comment: Quizá [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164286/c%c3%b3mo-imprimir-la-secuencia-de-n%c3%bameros-m%c3%ad-function-fibonacci) te ayude, ya que es la misma pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En javascript definir una variable sin valor es equivalente a definirla con valor = undefined. y no puedes hacer operaciones con un valor undefined.
A diferencia de C++ que definir un entero sin valor es igual a definirlo con valor = 0;

Solucion: solo define Z = 1 al inicio.

```js
let x = 1, y = 1, z = 1;
let result = 0;

while (z <= 4000000) {
    z = x + y;
    x = y;
    y = z;

    if (z % 2 == 0)
        result += z;
}

console.log(result);
```